# How can I observe changes to the DOM in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jquery-Mutation Summary https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/ "a JavaScript library that makes observing changes to the DOM fast, easy and safe"

It can be found here: https://github.com/joelpurra/jquery-mutation-summary

Here's an example of it at work: http://joelpurra.github.io/jquery-mutation-summary/example/demo.html

I'd like to be able to observe changes to the DOM in an iframe from a parent window. Here's my code

```
$(function() {
var $ChangeThere = $('#myframe') //iframe id myframe
    $ChangeThere.mutationSummary('connect', callback, [{
    all: true
}]);
function callback(summaries){
//something changes in iframe dom
    alert('change!');
}
});
```

The above code doesn't work. I'm accessing from the same domain as well.

Comment: You can't listen for changes in an IFRAME from a different domain. Can't access it for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

You should be able do the listening within the iFrame, then send the results back to the parent. You can establish a function in the parent, then update it from the iFrame like below.

Parent:

```
function alertfromiframe(message){
    alert(message);
}
```

iFrame:

```
$(function() {
var $ChangeThere = $('#frameContents') //iframe id myframe
    $ChangeThere.mutationSummary('connect', callback, [{
    all: true
}]);
function callback(summaries){
//something changes in iframe dom
    parent.alertfromiframe('change!');
}
});
```

Comment: I've tried it and it's not working. The function isn't working in the parent and it's only a function that displays an alert box for now.

Comment: Within the iFrame try console logging the parent function to see if it is defined. i.e. 'console.log(parent.alertfromiframe())' - from there you'll know if it is a problem communicating between the iframe and parent or a problem with the function. More simply, you could set a variable in the parent like 'var test - 'test'' and console.log(parent.test) from the iframe to see if the communication between iframe and parent is working.

Answer (score 0):

expose a method from a page that will be loaded as an iframe:

```
var RPC = require('frame-rpc');
var origin = document.referrer;

var rpc = RPC(window, window.parent, origin, {
    beep: function (n, cb) {
        document.querySelector('#n').textContent = n;
        cb(n * 111);
    }
});
```

then from the parent page containing the iframe:

```
var RPC = require('frame-rpc');
var frame = document.querySelector('iframe');
var usrc = new URL(frame.getAttribute('src'));
var origin = usrc.protocol + '//' + usrc.host;

frame.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
    var rpc = RPC(window, frame.contentWindow, origin);
    rpc.call('beep', 5, function (result) {
        document.querySelector('#result').textContent = result;
    });
});
```

The module you can find here: [substack/frame-rpc](https://github.com/substack/frame-rpc)
You can use wzrd.in/standalone/frame-rpc or

> npm install frame-rpc